# Java Interest Calculator won't compile, not sure why

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

I am writing an interest calculator in Java. The program prompts the user for input, and using that input  calculates interest on a certain bank account (checking, savings or CD).

That is the gist of my program and it is pretty simple. But right now I am stuck with exactly why the return statement is not working in the createAccount method. Any help would be appreciated.

Banker.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Banker {

// Array for type of bank account
public static void createAndShowGUI() {


    // Declare strings for period, balance, rate
    String period;
    String balance;
    String rate;
    String type;
    String input;

    // Prompt for account type
    String[] accttype = {"Checking", "Savings", "CD"}; // Array of bank acct types
    input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose account...",
            "Choose bank account type", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            accttype, // Array of acct types
            accttype[0]); // First choice


    // Prompt user for input
    period = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of periods (length):");
    balance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Beginning balance:");
    rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Interest rate (use decimal, example: .05 = 5%):");

    // Make Calculate button
    JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    // Make 2 Labels
    JLabel blabel = new JLabel("Period: " + period);
    JLabel plabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);

    // Setup window with flow layout and exit on close
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Interest Savings Calculator Plus");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Add combo box, calc button and labels
    frame.add(calculate);

    frame.add(plabel);
    frame.add(blabel);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static Account createAccount(String type, String checkno, String lengthm, String input) {
    String message = "Would you like to open another account?";
    String title = "Are you sure?";
    if (input == "Checking") {
        checkno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "First check number:");

        // display the JOptionPane showConfirmDialog
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);

        }
    } else if (input == "CD") {
        lengthm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Length until maturity:");

        // display the JOptionPane showConfirmDialog
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title,     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
            return input;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createAndShowGUI();
}
}
```

Acccount.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Account implements ActionListener {

JButton calculate;
private int period;
private int balance;
private int fbalance;
private int rate;
private int monthlyFee;
private String printstring;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Period: " + period + ", Balance: " + balance);
}

public int getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(int period) {
    this.period = period;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public int getFbalance() {
    return fbalance;
}

public void setFbalance(int fbalance) {
    this.fbalance = fbalance;
}

public String getPrintstring() {
    return printstring;
}

public void setPrintString(String printstring) {
    this.printstring = printstring;
}

public void calculate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        fbalance = balance + balance * rate - monthlyFee;
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    calculate();
}
}
```

Comment: "I am stuck with exactly why the return statement is not working in the createAccount method" How do you know it isn't working? Does it compile? If not, what's the error message? If it does, what happens when you run the program?

Comment: @user1810496.. Also I can't see where exactly are you using your `createAccount` method.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the return type of `createAccount` is `Account` and you are returning a `String` from it. It will fail there.

So, change your return type to `String`. And also to ensure that your method always returns a `value`. You should return a value from every path your code may follow. Alternatively, you can add a `return null;` at the end of the method (But you should also consider the previous statement).

But again, it's hard to understand that why you are returning a `string`, from `createAccount` method. And in fact you are not creating any account in that method at all. Please rename your method so as to reflect its exact purpose.

Secondly, you are comparing your `strings` using `==` operator, that will give you problems, once you come out of Compiler errors. You should use `equals` method to compare string: -

```
if (input == "Checking")
```

should be: -

```
if (input.equals("Checking"))
```

Comment: @mellamokb. Thanks. Edited post to reflect that part.

Answer (score 0):

Also you must add `return` clause when Account was not created inside one of the branches of `if-else`.

Answer (score 0):

Well First, follow Rohit's suggestions.

The other major problem is that not all your code paths return a value at all. (What happens if the input is "checking" ?)

Second, path that IS returning a value is placed AFTER the system Exit:

```
public static Account createAccount(String type, String checkno, String lengthm, String input) {
    String message = "Would you like to open another account?";
    String title = "Are you sure?";
    if (input == "Checking") {
        checkno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "First check number:");

        // display the JOptionPane showConfirmDialog
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);

        }
        // Return if input == checking not here
    } else if (input == "CD") {
        lengthm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Length until maturity:");

        // display the JOptionPane showConfirmDialog
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title,     JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
            return input;   // never gets here
        }
    }
}
```

Are you using an IDE? or just using a notepad? Are you paying attention to the compiler warnings? Always take care of warnings, they're likely latent runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks Rohit I made your corrections. That allowed my program to compile. Still having some problems though, thanks for those tips User. I actually noticed that was a large part I forgot: it is not supposed to System.exit I actually copy-pasted that from an example and forgot to edit it. I actually would like that value to be stored, when the User selects YES to return to the createAccount and loop it again. And if NO to pass these values to calculator? I **really** appreciate anyhelp you guys have to give. The logic of my program is not yet perfect so if you have any ideas there also would he

Comment: If you want a user to be able to create several accounts, you shouldn't be handling that logic inside the createAccount method; you need to implement it in the method that's calling the createAccount method. The basic idea is, inside an infinte loop, you ask the user if they want to create an account, if yes, call createAccount, if no, break out of the loop (and System.exit(0) or whatever you want to do)